# execution failed: execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed. TransactionPaymentApi_query_info

Tags: rust, wasm, frontend

We are currently depositing KSM tokens to our parachain using the following code:

```
kusamaApi.tx.xcmPallet.limitedReserveTransferAssets(params_here)
```

When executing the transaction, the KSM tokens are successfully transferred to the parachain. However, we are having trouble fetching the partial fee for this transaction on our frontend.

To fetch this fee, we are using the following code:

```
kusamaApi.tx.xcmPallet.limitedReserveTransferAssets(params_here).paymentInfo(account)
```

However, when we run this code, we encounter an error and are unable to display the fee. The error message states:

```
2023-04-06 11:47:22        RPC-CORE: call(method: Text, data: Bytes, at?: BlockHash): Bytes:: -32000: Client error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:

    0: 0x3c246 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x3ea1 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h32de9c76c9d5eb0c
    2: 0x95fd3 - <unknown>!TransactionPaymentApi_query_info
Uncaught (in promise) RpcError: -32000: Client error: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:

    0: 0x3c246 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x3ea1 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h32de9c76c9d5eb0c
    2: 0x95fd3 - <unknown>!TransactionPaymentApi_query_info

    at checkError (index.js?01d4:23:1)
    at RpcCoder.decodeResponse (index.js?01d4:38:1)
    at WsProvider.value (index.js?9439:232:1)
    at WebSocket.value (index.js?9439:215:1)
```

It is unclear what the exact problem is. Could someone provide further details or context to help us identify the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems that the front-end version of React is incorrect. I tested it by creating a new React application from scratch, and everything is functioning properly.